# How can I deduce the hypotenuse from the information given?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm going into Machine Learning and am currently brushing up on some Calculus on Coursera. Everything was going smoothly until I got to this word problem:

> A ladder rests against a wall. The top of the ladder touches the wall at height $12$ meters. The length of the ladder is  $4$ meters longer than the distance from the base of the ladder to the wall. Find the length of the ladder.

I am confused as to how to deduce the hypotenuse from the information given above. And have sat here trying different things with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: I added the "algebra-precalculus" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Draw a picture with the ladder. Label the sides of the triangle formed by the ladder, the wall, and the floor.  If you call the base x, the ladder is x+4. Then use the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $d$ be the distance from the ladder to the wall, and $l$ the length of the ladder.
Then

$l = d + 4; \tag 1$

since the wall is mos' likely perpendicular to the ground, we may deploy the Pythagorean theorem and write

$l^2 = (12)^2 + d^2; \tag 2$

substituting (1) into (2) yields

$(d + 4)^2 = 144 + d^2, \tag 3$

$d^2 + 8d + 16 = 144 + d^2, \tag 4$

$8d + 16 = 144 \Longrightarrow 8d = 128 \Longrightarrow d = 16M \Longrightarrow l = 20M. \tag 5$

Comment: Oh my. I distributed the 2 exponent to `d` and `4` individually instead of multiplying the expression by itself. Not the first time this has gotten me.

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen:  we're all learners, my friend!

Comment: No, the answer should be "at that angle, the ladder doesn't rest at the wall" ;-)

Comment: @DonQuiKong I wouldn't get on it, that's for sure!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Given the length of the wall as $12$.

Take the length of the base as $x$.

Since the length of the ladder $l$ is $4$ meters greater than the base, we have $l = x+4$

Now according to the pythagorean theorem we have,

$\begin{align}
(x+4)^2 &= 12^2 + x^2 \\
x^2 + 16 + 8x &= 144 + x^2 \\
8x &= 128 \\
x & = 16 
\end{align}$

So, the length of the ladder $l = x+4 = 16+4 = 20$

Comment: Nice graphic, ***+1***!

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note `4 times greater than the base` is ambiguous and could imply it is `x * 4` and not `x + 4`.

Comment: @FelixGuo "4 times greater" isn't ambiguous at all: it can only mean $x\times 4$ and never $x+4$. It was just a mistake, which has now been corrected.